# Troubles initializing NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, count, nsdictionary

I've been struggling a lot trying to translate this code from **Objective-C**

```
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid] forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];
```

...to **Swift**

```
var options:NSDictionary = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjects(UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Mid, forKeys: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey, count: 0);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why!
Here's what **XCode**'s output reported:

> Cannot invoke 'dictionaryWithObjects' with an argument list of type '(UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation, for keys: NSString!, count: IntegerLiteralConvertible)'

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about just

```
    let options = [UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey: UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Mid];`
```

---

the problem you are facing is that the constructor NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjects -- a) doesn't exist, b) that enums aren't AnyObject, c) that count is 0 but should be 1

```
    let o = UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Mid.toRaw() //toRaw makes it conform to AnyObject
    let k = UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey
    let options = NSDictionary(object: o, forKey: k)
```

Comment: Thanks! It just wanted that "toRaw": var options:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation.Mid.toRaw(), forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey);

Comment: toRaw is not a method anymore?